# How can I filter List<Map<String, dynamic>> to get a value in Flutter?

Tags: list, filter, flutter, where-clause

I have a json data and I am loading into `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` using await **jsonDecode.**.

Example, I have a;

1. amount = 12500
2. caliber = 24

and I need to filter the son to get maturity value: **689.19**

Also if I have a amount = 12500 and value = 689.19 I need to get caliber which is 24.

How can I filter List> json data to get a value in Flutter?

```
[
   {"amount": "5000", "caliber": "12", "maturity":  "484.25"},
   {"amount": "5000", "caliber": "24", "maturity":  "275.67"},
   {"amount": "7500", "caliber": "12", "maturity":  "726.38"},
   {"amount": "7500", "caliber": "24", "maturity":  "413.51"},
   {"amount": "10000", "caliber": "12", "maturity":  "968.50"},
   {"amount": "10000", "caliber": "24", "maturity":  "551.35"},
   {"amount": "12500", "caliber": "12", "maturity":  "1210.63"},
   {"amount": "12500", "caliber": "24", "maturity":  "689.19"},
   {"amount": "15000", "caliber": "12", "maturity":  "1452.76"},
   {"amount": "15000", "caliber": "24", "maturity":  "827.03"},
   {"amount": "15000", "caliber": "12", "maturity":  "1694.89"},
   {"amount": "17500", "caliber": "24", "maturity":  "964.87"},
   {"amount": "17500", "caliber": "36", "maturity":  "727.66"},
   {"amount": "17500", "caliber": "48", "maturity":  "613.53"},
   {"amount": "17500", "caliber": "60", "maturity":  "548.44"},
   {"amount": "20000", "caliber": "12", "maturity":  "1937.01"},
   {"amount": "20000", "caliber": "24", "maturity":  "1102.71"}
]
```

**UPDATE:**
With @Muldec help I finally got it.

First I load above son to  List as shown below. And apply @Muldec answer and it worked.

```
List<Map> myList = List<Map>.from(jsonDecode(jsonFastCalculation) as List);
final item = myList.firstWhere((e) => e['amount'] == '12500' && e['caliber'] == '24');
print(item['maturity']);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `firstWhere` or `where` methods on your list to get the `Map` element you need or a list of `Map` depending on your search criteria.

Supposing you are absolutely sure your search criteria will give you only one item (or that you only care of the first item meeting your criteria) here's an example of code with `firstWhere`:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> myList = ....;

final item = myList.firstWhere((e) => e['amount'] == '12500' && e['caliber'] == '24');
print(item['maturity']);
```

Finding the caliber based on the amount and the maturity is simply a mater of changing the test in the `firstWhere` method

Comment: I gor errr as; Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'firstWhere'.

Comment: This error indicated that your json data is not loaded in a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` as you stated before. Can you show us how you load your data ?

Comment: I update my question and it worked. Thank you very much

Comment: now I am having difficulty if I relic '12500' with '$amount' I get null error :(

Comment: when I print '$amount'  I can see I have value in it

Comment: sorry I found out. my amount was 10,000 remove the " , " and it worked.